# How does onBlur works on React?

Tags: reactjs

I am doing coursera course on react, and I have problem understanding a piece of code regarding onBlur.

In **handleBlur** function on removing the **(evt)** reacts gives error *Error: Maximum update depth exceeded.*

I am not able to understand why that is required here.

I am new in react.

```
....

class Contact extends Component {

    constructor(props){

        super(props);

        this.state = {
          ...

            touched : {
                firstname : false,
                lastname : false,
                telnum : false,
                email : false

            }
        };

       ...

        this.handleBlur = this.handleBlur.bind(this);
    }

   ...

    handleBlur = (field)=>(evt)=>{
        
        this.setState({
            touched:{...this.state.touched, [field]:true}
        });

    }

  ...

    render()
    {
        const errors = this.validate(this.state.firstname, this.state.lastname, this.state.telnum, this.state.email)

        return(
           ...
 <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
     <FormGroup row>
     <Label htmlFor="firstname" md={2}>First Name</Label>
     <Col md={10}>
     <Input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"
     placeholder="First Name"
     value={this.state.firstname}
     valid = {errors.firstname === ''}
     invalid = {errors.firstname !== ''}
     onBlur={this.handleBlur('firstname')}
     onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
     <FormFeedback>
         {errors.firstname}
      </FormFeedback>
     </Col>
   </FormGroup>
     
      ...

        );
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

Comment: you're executing a function instead of defining a it as a handler in your `onBlur` binding. notice how you did the same in your `onChange` event. thats how it should be done. to pass parameter you can use `this.handleBlur.bind(this, 'firstname')` instead

Comment: okay, so by defining an arrow function inside the **handleBlur** function, makes it a handler, and on removing it, it gets executed instead of being a handler(because of args I passed)??

Comment: `const a = func` is not the same as `const a = func()` braces, not the args.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `onBlur={this.handleBlur('firstname')}` runs immediately and React has an infinity loop on this event. you must wrapping your method with a function.

Use this code:

```html
<Input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname"
     placeholder="First Name"
     value={this.state.firstname}
     valid = {errors.firstname === ''}
     invalid = {errors.firstname !== ''}
     onBlur={() => this.handleBlur('firstname')}
     onChange={this.handleInputChange}
/>
```